# Wildcard subdomains through .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, wildcard, subdomain

Here's what I have:

Each state corresponds to numbers: -1, -2, -3, -4 etc. which are also $row[countryid]

Each city corresponds to numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. which are also $row[cityid]

( examples: qwikad.com/-1 or qwikad.com/1 )

The names of the states and cities are echoed by $xcountryname for the states and $xcityname for the cities

I'd like to convert all those links via htaccess into more user friendly subdomains.

So, qwikad.com/-1 should become alabama.qwikad.com and qwikad.com/1 should become auburn.qwikad.com etc. etc. etc.

Any ideas how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to point all of subdomains the the server and then you can use [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to match on the `%{HTTP_HOST}` to determine if you should do the rewrite or not. If you have a limited number of subdomains you can do this manually as follows.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Does it start with "alabama", if so do the rewrite on the next line
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alabama
RewriteRule (.*) /-1/$1 [L]
# Does it start with "auburn", if so do the rewrite on the next line
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^auburn
RewriteRule (.*) /1/$1 [L]
# ... and so on
```

For larger numbers of redirects you should use a [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) to hold the ID/Name relationships for the rewrite. This also provides you the option to update this file programmatically fairly easily. This example uses `([^\.]*)\.` to match anything in the hostname before the first `.` and then use it to look up the ID from the text field with the `%1` backreference.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteMap subdomains txt:/path/to/file/map.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]*)\.
RewriteRule (.*) /${subdomains:%1}/$1 [L]
```

**/path/to/file/map.txt**

```
#
# subdomain mappings
# comments start with a "#"
# key value pairs one per line
#
alabama   -1   # state
auburn     1   # city
something  2
else       3
```

Comment: Just tried what you suggested and it gives me a 500 error message.

Comment: I disabled the error log... so I don't know. But I was reading online that some hosting providers do not allow RewriteMap. Is that true? Maybe that's why it's not working.

Comment: Maybe, hard to say without the actual error message.

Comment: OK, I turned the error log back on and tested it again. Basically it says that "RewriteMap" not allowed in .htaccess. Is there any other way to do this bypassing .htaccess or without RewriteMap command?

Comment: The first example does not use `RewriteMap`.

Comment: Ah, yes. I kept testing using that second option and forgot about the first one. Ok, thanks!